# Change android phone's System date on button click from android application

Tags: android, date

I trying some stuffs with android as i am learning android development, now i have a scenario here.

- I want to change the android phone's system date through my application( **first i would like to know is this doable?** )

Layout is as below

[image: layout]

Now what i want is when the user clicks the button the date should increase by say 20 days
how can i do this.

i am unable to start...please help

Comment: What have you tried and what you won't unable to start? Can you provide more information?

Comment: unable to start in the sense i don't know, i don't know how can i get the system date and change it through my application. what inbuilt classes provides the functionality to get and set system dates

Comment: you want to change the mobile date when your press on the button?

Comment: yeah,it is what i want

Comment: that`s impossible. You need the SET_TIME permission and that permission is granted by system  only to applications that are in the Android system image. If You are able to gain that privilege you can easily change with the AlarmManager

Comment: if the phone is rooted then?

Comment: if it is rooted you can change the permission of /dev/alarm and use  SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(long). The better choice is to start startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS)); and let the user change it

Comment: Some more interesting stuff about this issue to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android ;)

Comment: a piece of code or classes involved would be helpful

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); to became root Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 666 /dev/alarm");

Comment: any fortune with your issue?

Comment: Why would you do this? Do you need to sync the device's time with server time so you will avoid any response errors caused by "request in the past/future"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I already said that's impossible. You need the `SET_TIME` permission and that permission is granted by system only to applications that are in the Android system image. If You are able to gain that privilege you can easily change with the AlarmManager. `SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis` write the /dev/allarm file

```
adb shell ls -l /dev/alarm
crw-rw-r-- system   radio     10,  46 2013-06-12 10:46 alarm
```

- `c` stays for `Character special file (stored in /dev).`
- system is the owner of the file
- radio is the group

system and radio have read and write permissions (rw-, tree bits, int value 6), the others have only the read permission (r, int value 4). So the file permission is `664`. If you can get root user (running `su`), you can change the permission of this file and wrote in it a new value. A bug report has been filled in order to ask google to allow apps to modify programmatically the mobile date but it has been declied. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4581)  the reference

Comment: nice exaplanation. you need to root the device to gain super user acess. + 1

Answer (score 4):

On Android, the only way for an application do have write access to the time&date is to get the SET_TIME permission, which is only possible for "applications that are in the Android system image or that are signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission." (see [signatureOrSystem protection level](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel)).

The only way for your application to reach this protection level is to run on a rooted device, or build and sign your own android rom.

If this is your case, you can easily use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or simply the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) instance.

Good luck!

Comment: I think there is more to it than just running on a rooted device.  I'm running my application on a rooted Nexus 7 and even though I can get an application to set the time from the GPS signal (Smart GPS Time, works like a champ), my code crashes immediately when I try it.  Any idea what's missing??

Answer (score 0):

Normal user applications does not have permission to change the device time. Read the answer by cashbash in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android) for the alternate option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, blackbelt is right; android lets us do a lot of cool things, but changing system time programmatically is not one of them.

Since I see that you are looking for more credible/official sources, I suggest you check out [this open ticket with Google](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4581), which suggests this is an open problem--it ought to work, but doesn't, and it doesn't seem Google is going to fix it anytime soon. The gist of it is that the SET_TIME protection level is set higher than it ought to be. (for more information on permissions, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel))

Although this is not quite the same as changing the time programmatically, you can still make the user change the system time for you if for some reason you do need system time to be changed. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799761/making-the-user-change-the-time-in-android) will explain how to go about implementing that if you want to go that route.

Hope this was helpful information!