# Change the time in android through code

Tags: android, clock, android-settings

Well I searched quit a lot on the new, and I found no good answer for that, unless your phone is rooted.
I am pretty sure you can do this in bash codes, but I have no idea where even to read about that.

I want to make an app with 2 buttons.
1st button will change the date of my phone 1 day forword
2nd button will change the hour of my phone 1 hour backword.

I want that the button will change the clock in the settings of phone
thank you all:)

Comment: `bash` - which is not normally present on Android and non-trivial to install - is not an alternative to doing something as root.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible for non-system apps that don't have a special permission.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android)