# set device time programmatically in android

Tags: android, datetime, time, timezone

I need to set device time dynamically.if it possible please guide me

So far as I tried

**MainActivity.java**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    
c.set(2010, 1, 1, 12, 00, 00);
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is menifest.xml?

Comment: try my answer and vote downers give the description also before voting down

Comment: @Glenn-- I am already follow this code but i got error like this "Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: setTime: Neither user 10095 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME."

Comment: @SpryTechies i am using your code i got above error in my log cat

Comment: your app must have system permission, you need to install your app as system app.

Comment: @markas can you explain clearly?

Comment: if your device is rooted, uninstall first your app in data, and push your apk in system/app/

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"/> set this in the manifest and try again please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android do have a look at this link it will solve your error

Comment: have your problem resolved

Comment: @markas how to install syste/app dynamically from ide without adb shell?

Answer (score 2):

```
//set Time to device
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2013, 8, 15, 12, 34, 56);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());

//   and set in Manifest.xml
 <!-- Allows applications to set the system time -->
    <permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"
        android:protectionLevel="signature|system"
      />
```

and follow this link for more help [How to set mobile system time and date in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android)
I think it may help u

Comment: Please add some description with piece of code to make it better understandable.

Comment: This gives me error 

java.lang.SecurityException: setTime: Neither user 10298 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME.