# Change phone time and date using flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

Is there any way to change phone's system time and date from phone settings programmatically using flutter. I need to change the phones date and time using my app for a purpose. Is there any way? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your can use [app_settings: ^4.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) package to open time and date setting. You can open wifi, location, Bluetooth setting also through this package.
but if you have to programmatically change the date and time you have to use java code for this purpose
I hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437547/programmatically-set-system-time) will help you for changing the time programmatically in java