# Can we change a device time with a custom app?

Tags: android

I need to sync my android application time with server. How can I achieve the same?
or is there any ways to change device time.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeManager timeManager = TimeManager.getInstance();

 // Set clock time to noon
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
 long timeStamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
 timeManager.setTime(timeStamp);
```

Edit the 0s and 12 as per your choice

NB:
You should add
`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.SET_TIME" />` 
in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this if you plan to have your app publish in the PlayStore, or update the time to the server time.

You need [SignatureOrSystem](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element#plevel) permission in order to change the time date as per the server.

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android) you will get more detail.